# Slur between two different notes

Tags: pdftex, musixtex

I have a problem with slur initiation and termination between two different note.
I provide an image as example.
How can i do this bar?

[image]

This is an example of implementation but the slur on the last bar start on the first note instead the fourth.[image]

```
\input musixtex
\setstaffs1{1}
\setclef1{\treble}
\generalmeter{\meterfrac44}
\nobarnumbers
\startextract

\Notes \qp \qp \ds \Tqbu ghi \en
\bar

\notesp\ibl0i0\qbp0j\en
\Notes\nbbbl0\qb0k\tbl0\qb0j\en
\Notes \Dqbl ij \en
\Notes \Dqbl kl \en
\notesp\ibl0i0\qbp0m\en
\Notes\nbbbl0\qb0n\tbl0\qb0m\en
\bar

\Notes \isluru0n \Qqbl lokn \en
\Notes \tslur0n \Qqbbl nonm \en
\Notes  \cu l \ds \en
\endextract
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write the beam manually, which allows to insert the start of the slur within the beam instead of before. Manual beams are started with `\ibu` (upper) or `\ibl` (lower) with three arguments, a reference number, the pitch, and slope. For example `\ibl0l1` starts a lower beam at pitch `l` that goes slightly up. Then you add each note individually with `\qb{reference number}{pitch}`, or multiple notes with `\qb{reference number}{notes}`. The last note of the beam can be denoted with `\tqb{reference number}{pitch}`.

Code:

```
\setstaffs1{1}
\setclef1{\treble}
\generalmeter{\meterfrac44}
\nobarnumbers
\startextract

\Notes \qp \qp \ds \Tqbu ghi \en
\bar

\notesp\ibl0i0\qbp0j\en
\Notes\nbbbl0\qb0k\tbl0\qb0j\en
\Notes \Dqbl ij \en
\Notes \Dqbl kl \en
\notesp\ibl0i0\qbp0m\en
\Notes\nbbbl0\qb0n\tbl0\qb0m\en
\bar

\Notes \ibl0l1\qb0{lok}\isluru0n\tqb0n\en
\Notes \tslur0n\Qqbbl nonm \en
\Notes  \cu l \ds \en
\endextract
```

Result:

[image]